# Task results are saved only when all tasks are done

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, django-celery

I want to monitor/report task statuses, but tasks are saved only when all tasks are done. I want them to be saved as soon as they start.

'''inside my Queue project'''
celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Queue.settings')
app = Celery('Queue',
    broker='redis://localhost:6379',
    backend='django-db',
    task_track_started=True,
    include=['index.tasks'])
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

inside "index" app
tasks.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import shared_task, current_task
import time

@shared_task
def gozle():
   time.sleep(15)
   return 1
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    gozle.delay()
    return HttpResponse('<a href="admin/">admin</a>')
```

I expect that as I visit index page my task be triggered and be recorded into ResultTask, but it waits 15 seconds then be recorded.

Answer (score 0):

The start of the task should be acknowledged immediately, you should see in your celery server a log entry that says that `gozle` task started, then it wait 15 seconds and will exit, this exit state will also be on the `celery` server log. If that is not the case maybe it has something to do with `task_acks_late` enabled in `celery` config, here is the [doc](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-task_acks_late), making it only acknowledge tasks after they end.

Comment: It is acknowledged immadiately, but it is not saved in database until task is done. So i cannot get information about its status.